# Cannot get true contact's group from Android device?

Tags: android, contacts, addressbook, contactgroups

I tried to get all group from android device with below code. Then I put all group name and id in arraylist.

```
Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI;
            String GR_ID = ContactsContract.Groups._ID;
            String GR_TITLE = ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE;
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor groupCursor = cr.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                    ContactsContract.Groups._ID + " ASC");
            while (groupCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String group_id = groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(GR_ID));
                String group_name = groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(GR_TITLE));

                Group grp = new Group(group_name);
                grp.setId(group_id);

                arrayPersonal.add(grp);
            }
            groupCursor.close();
```

This is result 
[image]

Some group have different id but same name. I dont know why?
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by selecting where **ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'com.google'**

I came across this because I queried for the ACCOUNT_TYPE column to see what it contained, and some of the entries were "com.google" and others were "DeviceOnly".  I have some other constraints on my group query, taken from an internal Android library ([GrepCode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html)), thus it seems wise to use them. Here is my entire selection statement (for the CursorLoader)

```
    private static final String CONTACT_GROUP_SELECTION = ContactsContract.Groups.AUTO_ADD + " = 0 "
        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = 'com.google' "
        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME + " NOT NULL  "
        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.FAVORITES + " = 0 "
        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + " = 0  ";
```